# AngularJS migrating from Gulp to Webpack 5

Tags: angularjs, webpack, gulp

I'm migrating my AngularJS from Gulp to Webpack. I'm currently facing the problem, that I can't use my templatecache. I tried using [angular-templatecache-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-templatecache-webpack-plugin), but it doesnt support Webpack 5 and as it seems it's not longer maintained by the author.

Is there a way to create the angular template cache like gulp did?

Comment: can you share some code?